# How this declaration (x=0.12378e+3) mean 123.8?

Tags: c, declaration

How this declaration (x=0.12378e+3) mean 123.8?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{ float x=0.12378e+3;
printf("%.1f",x); }
```

Comment: Do you understand what `e+3` means?

Comment: That's scientific notation.

Comment: It is rounded because you specified *one decimal place* with `%.1f`

Comment: What exactly are you unclear about?

Comment: Although there's a variety of [indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) both popular and obscure, the style you're using here isn't one of them. It's worth picking one that you like and sticking to it so you have some consistency in your code. Indentation communicates both style and intent, so having it all confused makes bugs way harder to find.

Answer (score 4):

> How this declaration (x=0.12378e+3) mean 123.8?

**It doesn't.**

```
0.12378e+3
```

is just

```
0.12378 * 10 * 10 * 10
```

which would be

```
123.78
```

The "problem" is here

```
printf("%.1f",x);
         ^^^
```

Notice the `.1` after the `%` which means that you only want 1 digit after the `.` Consequently, 123.78 is rounded to 123.8 before being printed.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{ 
    float x=0.12378e+3;  // or float x=123.78;

    printf("%.1f\n",x);   // Will print 1 digit after the .
    printf("%f\n",x);     // Will print at default number of digits after the .
    printf("%.50f\n",x);  // Will print 50 digits after the .
}
```

Output:

```
123.8
123.779999
123.77999877929687500000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here you see how the last print out is the closest you can get to the value 123.78, i.e. 123.7799987792968750

In other words - the value 123.78 can't be represented exactly in a `float` but as you can see, you get a lot closer than 123.8

Answer (score 1):

> 0.12378e+3

This is scientific notation for 123.78 (i.e., take 0.12378 and move the decimal to the right 3 places). You get 123.8 because of rounding.